# I don't get a database file when running my SQLAlchemy code

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I am trying to make a database in my flask project. When running this code I don't get any errors. But i'm supposed to get a .db file in my directory. Which I don't. Any ideas? :)

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from os import path

db = SQLAlchemy()
DB_NAME = "database.db"

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'key123'
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = f'sqlite:///{DB_NAME}'
    db.init_app(app)
    return app

def create_database(app):
    if not path.exists('website/' + DB_NAME):
        db.create_all(app=app)
```

Comment: Where  do you expect to find it? `sqlite:///dbname` will create a db in the current working directory, but you appear to be looking in a subdirectory 'website'.

Comment: 'website' is the current working directory :)

Comment: are you actually calling the `create_database` function?

Answer (score 0):

Your `DB_URI` is not a path, rather, it's a [protocol string](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html#database-urls) which instructs your program how to connect to your database.

It looks like you're trying to connect to your database and if the database doesn't exist, create it. Here's how I would go about doing that:

```py
# I'd suggest working with sqlite directly
import sqlite3

def test_or_create_database(DB_NAME):
    """Try connecting to your database, if the db doesn't exist, create it"""
    
    DB_URI = f'sqlite:///{DB_NAME}'

    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(DB_URI)
        conn.cursor()
    
     # Something went wrong
     # You can try to catch the error and fix, or break
     except Exception as exc:
        print(exc)


# --------------------
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from os import path


db = SQLAlchemy()
DB_NAME = "database.db"

def create_app():

    # Consider running your test or create db before anything:
    test_or_create_database(DB_NAME)

    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'key123'
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = f'sqlite:///{DB_NAME}'
    db.init_app(app)    
    return app
```

Comment: Does this solve your issue @PeroDoesStuff ?